# How to install SquirrelMail on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, squirrelmail

I'm trying to install SquirrelMail on Ubuntu 18.04LTS but when i run the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install squirrelmail
```

I got this:

```
Unable to locate package squirrelmail
```

I was trying to investigate but never asked before so i want to know how and if this is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install with sources indeed:

Dowload: `https://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrelmail/files/stable/1.4.22/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc`

Unzip: `unzip squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip`

And run config: `./configure`

Comment: I'll check it today. thanks.

Comment: The console give next error `unzip:  cannot find or open squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip, squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip.zip or squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip.ZIP` after `wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrelmail/files/stable/1.4.22/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc`  any help?

Comment: have you move to the right folder you downloaded it